# Replace default marker on google geoxml map overlays?

Tags: google-maps, wordpress, google-maps-markers, wordpress-geo-mashup

I am pulling georss data from feeds and overlaying them onto my map with Google Maps Geoxml. How do I replace the default markers that appear on these map overlays? Currently they are default blue pins but I would like to remove and replace it with something more appropriate for my theme.

I am working on a map for a Wordpress childtheme specifically using the Geo Mashup Plugin.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Which version of Google Maps API are you using?

Comment: V3. Any ideas on how I can get this to work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using google maps api V3, use geoxml3.(http://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/)

the original geoxml is made for google maps v2.

You can use any markers you want by specifying the "markerOptions" in the "geoXML3.parser Options" see: http://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/wiki/ParserReference

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var customIcon = new GIcon();
customIcon.image = "./images/customPin.png";
customIcon.shadow = "./images/customShadow.png";
customIcon.iconSize = new GSize(12, 20);
customIcon.shadowSize = new GSize(22, 20);
customIcon.iconAnchor = new GPoint(6, 20);
customIcon.infoWindowAnchor = new GPoint(5, 1);
```

P.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I've found this only works for data points pulled directly from the blog. I am specifically trying to change markers on GGeoxml overlay maps that pulls geodata from other rss feeds.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

> Thanks for the help but I've found
>   this only works for data points pulled
>   directly from the blog. I am
>   specifically trying to change markers
>   on GGeoxml overlay maps that pulls
>   geodata from other rss feeds. Any
>   other ideas? – thisisangelng

It looks like the default ballon icon cannot be changed. Havent found standard for specifying icon in geoRSS. What about to change rss to kml?

P.